# Problem with a console whoile executing program

Tags: java, junit

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
      
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter area code: ");
          int areaCode = scan.nextInt();
          
          System.out.println("Enter number: ");
          int localNumber = scan.nextInt();
          
          String phoneNumber = "(" + areaCode + ")-" + localNumber;
          
          System.out.println("Calling number "+phoneNumber);
            
    
        }
    
    }
```

Execution is ok, program asks to enter two int variables, but when I try to submit my task I got this kind message in console:

```sh
Number of passing tests: 0
Number of failing tests: 2

--- Details ---

JUnit version 4.11
.E.E
Time: 0.053
There were 2 failures:
1) areaCode222Number3334444_ShouldPrintFormattedNumber(MainTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[]Calling number (222)...> but was:<[Enter area code: 
Enter number: 
]Calling number (222)...>
```

How to handle it? Should I have to clean up console??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the automated test does not expect "Enter area code: " and "Enter number: " messages printed. Just remove two `System.out.println` sentences which print these lines from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after every occurence of the nextInt sentence :

field.nextLine();

This method advances the Scanner instance (scan) past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Your code should look like this:

-- collapsed package and imports statements --

```
public class Main {



public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter area code: ");
      int areaCode = scan.nextInt();
      scan.nextLine();
  
  System.out.println("Enter number: ");
  int localNumber = scan.nextInt();
  scan.nextLine();
 
  String phoneNumber = "(" + areaCode + ")-" + localNumber;
  
  System.out.println("Calling number "+phoneNumber);    
}
}
```

***EDIT:*** Syntaxe.